# How to set Google cloud Storage bucket (GCS) file object expiration (TTL) using CLI

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I want to set a policy to a new GCS bucket so that files expire in 14 days (TTL, time to live, or lifecycle ends).

I use

```
gsutil mb \
  -p ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} \
    gs://$GCS_BUCKET_NAME \
  --retention 14d
```

it doesn't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 6):

I found out that I misunderstood the intention of `--retention` flag after reading GCS bucket TTL and retention policy more carefully.

A retention policy, `--retention`, is to govern how long objects in the bucket must be retained, not when it shall expire or to be deleted.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock

for example,
`--retention 14d` means the objects are not allowed to be deleted within 14 days. It doesn't mean the objects has 14d lifecycle and shall expire and be deleted after 14 days.

If we want to set file objection expiration or TTL correctly for a GCS bucket, do the following instead

```
 # set GCS bucket object TTL
  echo '    
  {
      "rule":
      [
        {
          "action": {"type": "Delete"},
          "condition": {"age": 14}
        }
      ]
    }
  ' > gcs_lifecycle.tmp
  gsutil lifecycle set gcs_lifecycle.tmp gs://$GCS_BUCKET_NAME
  rm gcs_lifecycle.tmp
```